# Combine a column while grouping on another column with similar values

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, rdbms

I have been working on a SQL Server stored procedure to find a solution illustrated in the results table below. I am close in my solution however I get multiple results on a column I would like to have grouped altogether.

```
DECLARE @fiscal_year AS INT
SET @fiscal_year = '2016'

SELECT
    [ActionDate] AS [PPDate],
    SUM([GAL].[GCount]) AS [GCount],
    SUM([GAL].[LCount]) AS [LCount],
    CONCAT(SUM([GAL].[GCount]), ' Gain(s): (', [GAL].[GComments], '); ', SUM([GAL]. 
    [LCount]), ' Loss(es): (',  [GAL].[LComments], ')') AS [Details]
FROM
    [dbo].[TableA] [GAL]
GROUP BY
    [GAL].[ActionDate], [GAL].[GainComments], [Gal].[LossComments]
```

I have a table as follows.

Table A:

```
ID  ActionDate  GCount  GainRID GComments   LCount  LossRID LComments
1   2013-06-04  1       35      John        0       -1      NULL
2   2013-06-04  2       35      M & R       0       -1      NULL
3   2014-01-10  1       60      Paul        0       -1      NULL
4   2014-01-10  1       60      Mona        0       -1      NULL
5   2013-10-05  3       58      Tim         0       -1      NULL
6   2013-10-05  2       58      Ruby        0       -1      NULL
7   2013-10-05  0       -1      NULL        2       50      Jude & Mo
8   2013-10-05  0       -1      NULL        1       50      Frank
9   2013-10-05  0       -1      NULL        1       50      Linda
10  2014-01-10  0       -1      NULL        1       70      Eliz
11  2014-01-10  0       -1      NULL        1       70      Georgina
12  2014-01-10  0       -1      NULL        1       70      Christina
13  2013-10-05  0       -1      NULL        2       64      Joan & Mike
14  2013-10-05  0       -1      NULL        1       64      Mitch
```

...and I would like to have it grouped by Action Date, using the SUM() function on the GainCount and LossCount fields. The Details field is combined by
GainReasonID, LossReasonID, Gain and Loss Comments such that the table ends up like this.

```
Results
PPDate      GCount  LCount  Details
2013-06-04  2       0       "(2) Gains: 2(35) -- John, M & R 
                             (0) Losses: "
2013-10-05  2       3       "(2) Gains: 2(58) -- Tim, Ruby
                             (3) Losses: 3(50) -- Jude & Mo, Frank, Linda , 
                                 2(64) -- Joan & Mike, Mitch"
2014-01-10  2       3       "(2) Gains: 2(60) -- Paul, Mona
                             (3) Losses: 3(70) -- Eliz, Georgina, Christina"
```

Comment: Tag your question with dbms!

Comment: DO NOT post image.  Please change to text.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2016